# Intercompatibility between std.stdio.File and std.stream.*

Tags: io, d, standard-library

Is there any good way to turn a `std.stdio.File` into something that is an instance of a stream from `std.stream`?

Reason: I find myself wanting a generic logging utility working on streams, and I want to pass it `std.stdio.stderr` which is a `std.stdio.File`.

Comment: Please note that std.stream is deprecated.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yeah, I saw that poking around some more. Damn shame, a big standard library with no streams. When are we going to get Tango for D2?

Comment: Use ranges instead. They're like streams, but are generalized to more than just bytes. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the deprecated `std.stream` module, use ranges.

```cpp
import std.stdio;
import std.range;
import std.algorithm;
import std.typecons;
import std.conv;

// Log levels
enum LEVEL {
    DEBUG,
    INFO,
    WARN
};
alias LogMsg = Tuple!(LEVEL, string); // Should be a struct, but I'm lazy

void main() {
    // Get a writer, which is an OutputRange
    auto writer = stderr.lockingTextWriter();

    // Some messages. Can be any InputRange, not just an array
    auto messages = [
        LogMsg(LEVEL.DEBUG, "Log message 1"),
        LogMsg(LEVEL.INFO, "Log message 2"),
        LogMsg(LEVEL.WARN, "Log message 3"),
    ];

    // Write each message to the writer
    put(writer, messages
        // transform LogMsg's into strings to write.
        // Bonus points: use chain instead of ~ to avoid allocation
        .map!(msg => msg[0].to!string ~ ": " ~ msg[1] ~ "\n")
    );
}
```

Comment: Do ranges have dynamic dispatch of some kind?

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen Yes, use the wrappers in [std.range.interfaces](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range_interfaces.html)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [derr](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_cstream.html#.derr) from [cstream](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_cstream.html).

example:

```
import std.stream;
import std.cstream;

void main() {
    ubyte[] data = cast(ubyte[])"someData";
    OutputStream stream = derr;
    stream.write(data);
}
```

Btw. there is a [logging module](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_experimental_logger.html) in D standard lib